# React-bootstrap: formatting issue with React component wrapping DropdownButton

Tags: react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a React component that wraps a `DropdownButton`:

```
class MyDropdown extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <DropdownButton title='My Dropdown'>
                <MenuItem>Action</MenuItem>
            </DropdownButton>
        );
    }
}
```

However, when I use it inside a `Navbar` it doesn’t render using the same CSS formatting as a “regular” `DropdownButton`.

The code below displays a “regular” `DropdownButton` alongside a `MyDropdown`. The difference between the two components can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh1n4.jpg):

```
class MyHeader extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Navbar brand='Example' fixedTop fluid>
                <Nav>
                    <NavItem href='#'>Link</NavItem>
                    <DropdownButton title='Dropdown'>
                        <MenuItem>Action #1.1</MenuItem>
                    </DropdownButton>
                    <MyDropdown />
                </Nav>
            </Navbar>
        );
    }
}
```

---

My question is: is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? What’s the recommended way to wrap a `DropdownButton` so this doesn’t happen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, simple fix, just add navItem={true} to the DropdownButton component.

Here's an example that works for me:

`<DropdownButton eventKey={2} title='Adopta una Mascota' navItem={true}>
                                <MenuItem eventKey='1' href="/why">¿Por qué adoptar y no comprar?</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem eventKey='2' href="/process">Proceso de adopción</MenuItem>
                            </DropdownButton>`

(I'd like to post a screenshot of navbar but don't have the reputation yet)
hope this helps.